# From Option to iterator

Tags: iterator, rust, type-erasure

I have a function which consumes an iterator:

```
fn func<T: iter::Iterator<Item = char>>(i: T) {
    //...   
}
```

I need to write a function whose input is an `Option<char>` (type `char` is not important here, just for illustrative purpose), and depends on the value of input, it should create an empty or an once iterator. My [solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8d86c98234f70e26ef8001b9cee1499f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) is:
    use std::iter;

```
fn option_iter(input: Option<char>) {
    let i: Box<iter::Iterator<Item = char>> = if let Some(input) = input {
        Box::new(iter::once(input))
    } else {
        Box::new(iter::empty())
    };
}
```

I find this ugly because of type erasure by `Box`. I cannot use:

```
let i = if let Some(input) = input {
    iter::once(input)
} else {
    iter::empty()
};
func(i);
```

because the compiler complains the types of two branches are different. Is there any method which does not use `Box` for this situation?

Comment: If you can change `func` to take `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator`, you can just write `func(input)`. Also, `Iterator` is in the prelude, so you don't need to `use std::iter;` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option` has an [`iter` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.iter) that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that, yay yay.